# IOS RxSwift Create Array of Observable from Observable array

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I'm building a chain function which the flow is to take result from previous function and loop through each element do some calculation and final return back the original array

I have

```
func(A) -> Observable<[Object]>
func(B)(Object) -> Observable<Object>
```

How do we make the chaining like this?

```
Observable<[Object]> -> [Observable<Object>] -> Observable<[Object]>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can chain functions with ´flatMap´ operator:

```
funcA().flatMap{ objects in 
    Observable.from(objects)
}
.flatMap{ eachObject in
    funcB(eachObject)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do we need to call .toArray() on the last line?

Comment: Yes, if you want your output to be array :)